# TinyTag import error python 3.3

Tags: python-3.x, mp3, metadata

I have been trying to import tinytag into python to be able to read mp3 tags but I keep receiving the same error. This is the code I am running

```
    from tinytag import TinyTag
    tag = TinyTag.get('/some/music.mp3)

    print(tag.album)
```

and the error I recieve from this is

```
    ImportError: No module named 'tinytag'
```

If anyone could give me any information on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated or can suggest another reader to use that is compatible with python 3.

Comment: Is tinytag installed on your system? It is not a part of standard python library

Comment: No I'm struggling to get it installed, I'm new to python and don't know how to install it can you help in anyway

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I'm new to Python and I struggled with this but I worked it out eventually. I'm sure there is  better way, but this worked (on windows, with my examples)

- I installed a python module called easy_install (bundled with
  setuptools). you can Google this. In the directory \Python26\Scripts you should see an exe file called easy_install if this has worked
- Then I downloaded TinyTag to my pc eg 
  \downloads\tinytag-0.6.1.tar.gz
- Then in note pad I wrote a small text file called myinstall.bat  with
  the contents

easy_install C:/downloads/tinytag-0.6.1.tar.gz

pause

- then saved it into \Python26\Scripts and ran it (the pause keeps the
  window open so you can see it worked)

Subsequently I started using some software called JetBrains to code with (it's commercial but there is a free edition) and that has an install tool built in which is even easier) I hope this helps